# Randomly nesting and populating arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I understand javascript and its syntax, but I am relatively unfamiliar with its standard functions.

For a basic javascript game I'm working on, I need to randomly nest arrays like so:

Array with 2 items (two nested arrays)

1. nested array with 2 items (two nested arrays)

   - nested array with 2 items

     - item
     - item
   - nested array with 1 item

     - item
2. nested array with 2 items (one nested array, one empty slot)

   - nested array with 1 item

     - item
   - null

I hope that was clear enough; if someone could post links to some docs or give me pointers on how I should structure my code, I'll probably be able to take it from there.

Comment: So the nesting is to be random, but what about the items? Predetermined, random? Can items only appear two levels deep into the structure? Do you want a random depth as well or is it always supposed to be 2 levels? What is an empty slot? undefined? null? empty subarray?

Comment: @Adam Zalcman I'd want items to appear only on the 2nd level and for there to be a fixed depth. The items don't matter that much as I'm only looking to create a basic script right now - I can always add complexity later on.

Comment: Oh, and the empty item is just null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below provides a few functions with `build2LevelArray()` solving your problem. It creates an array of length no greater than 2 (you can tweak this replacing `3` in `buildArray()` with some other number). Empty array is never returned since we return `null` instead. Items of the returned array are themselves `null` values or arrays. Each item which is an array has length no greater than 2 and all its elements are generated by `buildItem()` (hardcoded `1` as an example in `buildItem()`).

```
function buildItem() {
  // This function implements item generation algorithm, for now, all items are 1s
  return 1;
}

function buildArray(itemGenerator) {
  var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*3); // Random integer between 0 and 2 (inclusive)
  if (n == 0) {
    return null; // Return nulls instead of empty arrays
  }
  var a = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a.push(itemGenerator());
  }
  return a;
}

function build1LevelArray() {
  return buildArray(buildItem);
}

function build2LevelArray() {
  return buildArray(build1LevelArray);
}
```

Example values it generated:

```
null            // no array
[null]          // example array of length 1
[[1, 1]]        // another example array of length 1
[null, [1, 1]]  // example array of length 2
[[1], [1, 1]]   // another example array of length 2
```

Comment: Awesome answer - thanks a lot! Too bad I can only upvote once ... thanks again.